# Алгоритм сжатия с заранее определённым словарём

Tags: алгоритм, сжатие

Существует ли алгоритм сжатия, который позволяет заранее определить словарь, который будет использоваться при распаковке?

То есть:
Я хочу на стороне сервера сжимать статьи про котиков и передавать их на клиент, а значит я заранее определяю словарь:

```
Котик, кошечка, ми-ми-ми, мусик ...
```

Этот словарь получает и сервер и клиент, он не изменяется более никогда, либо изменяется по взаимному договору клиента и сервера.
Теперь при сжатии алгоритм использует заранее сформированный словарь (плюс, если требуется, создаёт дополнительный словарь конкретно для сжимаемых данных).

Comment: ZSTD так умеет. Сначала обучаете его на примерных данных, потом - в бой.

Comment: @gbg, оформите как ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ZSTD](https://github.com/facebook/zstd) так умеет. Сначала обучаете его на примерных данных, потом - в бой

**Сжатие со словарём:**

Создание словаря:

```
zstd --train FullPathToTrainingSet/* -o dictionaryName
```

Сжатие со словарём:

```
zstd -D dictionaryName FILE
```

Распаковка со словарём:

```
zstd -D dictionaryName --decompress FILE.zst
```